# Inspect Element Not working/blank

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend, web-inspector

Whenever I try inspect element nothing comes up. I'm on Chrome. I get the

```
Elements | Network | Sources | Timeline | Profiles | Resources | Audits | Console
```

menu and then a sub menu in each of those of the following:

```
Console | Search | Emulation | Rendering
```

Where do I go to see the source code? Previously I would just inspect element and it would come up, did I mess around with the configuration accidentally?

Thanks!

Comment: try open new tab and enter view-source:<your page address>

Comment: There may be another panel open. Do you have a little handle icon somewhere on the right hand side? If so grab that and pull the panel down.

Comment: there is magnifier icon on left side of bar you can use that for inspecting

Comment: @BillyMoat Thank you! There was another panel covering the code! I know its dumb but as a newb these are the little things that happen to you thanks!

Comment: @BillyMoat If you write your response as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Ha! Glad it was something simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be another panel open. Do you have a little handle icon somewhere on the right hand side? If so grab that and pull the panel down.

Answer (score 3):

It might be a cache issue. **After opening Developer Tools(F12)** in Chrome, refresh cache by pressing **Ctrl + F5**.

Answer (score 0):

The source can be found by elements.

Do you see the magnifier next to elements?
In that case you can select the element that you want to inspect

If you want to view the javascript or loaded files you can view these at sources. By using Ctrl+O you can select the source file you want to see.

If your information is loaded by AJAX, your Javascript cant be inspected. HTML loaded by AJAX can be viewed by first open the page where your content will be shown, and after that you can inspect the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CTRL+U, that works better than view-source

Comment: Uhm, not better, it's the short cut that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Somehow on the toolbar (where we also have filter option), Img tab was selected instead of All.

Answer (score 0):

There may be another panel open. Do you happen to have a little handle icon somewhere on the right-hand side? If so, grab the handle icon and pull the panel down.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: direct copy of Billy Moat's answer from 2014 in this thread. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Go to any other storyboard file and select any element there, now return back to previous file(where inspect element was not working). Now select any element here, This should work now

PS: This hack worked for me